# Java CriteriaBuilder: the type passed CriteriaBuilder.In is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to JAVA but I've had experience with other languages e.g. (C, C++, PHP)

So I encountered this error at work and I'm completely stumped.
Here is the snippet of the function:

```
    private void addIn(CriteriaAPIHelper<TgEvent> helper,
        List<Predicate> condList, Path<?> path, Object value) {

    if (this.isNullOrEmpty(value)) {
        return;
    }
    if (value instanceof Object[] && ((Object[]) value).length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (value instanceof List && ((List) value).isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    if (value instanceof Set && ((Set) value).isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    condList.add(helper.getBuilder().in(path).value(value));
}
```

The problem is at this line:

```
condList.add(helper.getBuilder().in(path).value(value));
```

The error is:

```
The method value(capture#7-of ?) in the type CriteriaBuilder.In<capture#7-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
```

I've tried casting "value" to Object but still, the error persists.
Am I missing something? It would mean a lot if someone could explain this. 
Thank you very much

---

Relevant source:

```
public class CriteriaAPIHelper<Entity extends AbstractPflameEntity> {
    ....
    private CriteriaBuilder builder;

    public CriteriaBuilder getBuilder() {
    return builder;
    ....
}
```

Comment: Please also include code for `CriteriaAPIHelper` as it seems to be some custom code instead of library.

Comment: I've added it although i think, for this part of the code it just returns the CriteriaBuilder.

Comment: What jpa you are using? I tried with no error using hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.